# criterion for $f \circ g$ to be Riemann integrable

Tags: calculus, integration, measure-theory

Is there a weak but sufficient criterion for the composition of two Riemann integrable functions to be Riemann integrable? In particular, I'm interested in the case where we have a sequence of Riemann integrable functions $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ and we consider the composition:

$$ f=lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(f_{n-1}(...(f_1)) \tag{*}$$

I'm aware that $f$ is not generally Riemann integrable. But, are there useful criteria that might apply to each of the $f_n$ such that $f$ is Riemann integrable?

Note: I'm also aware that the composition of Borel measurable functions is always Borel measurable. This makes me wonder what might happen if all the $f_n$ are Riemann and Borel...

Comment: Related discussion: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/20045/about-the-riemann-integrability-of-composite-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say this is on an interval $[a,b]$, with each $f_i$ defined on a union of closed intervals containing 
 $f_{i-1} \circ \ldots \circ f_1([a,b])$.

A sufficient condition should be: for each $i$ from $1$ to $n-1$, we can write  $f_{i} \circ \ldots \circ f_1([a,b]) = A_i \cup B_i$ such that
all discontinuities of $f_{i+1}$ are in $B_i$, and for every subset $S$ of $B_i$ such that $S$ has measure $0$, $(f_i \circ \ldots \circ f_1)^{-1}(S)$ also has measure $0$.